# Logic to solve a rock paper scissor permutation/DP problem

Tags: algorithm, logic, dynamic-programming, permutation, game-theory

Permutation/Combination problems are always a tough nut to crack.

Given a Rock paper scissors game of N turns played by 2 people (round win : 1 point, round draw : 0)
Player 1 sequence has been provided. **Player 2 needs to win without playing same move twice in a row.

Find Number of ways to win** (with Mod 1000000007 to prevent integer overflow).

**(Win condition - Player 2 has more round wins than Player 1)**
(R- Rock, P- Paper, S-Scissor)
e.g. 3 rounds - RRR
Player 2 can win by PRP, PSP, RPR
Answer : 3
e.g. 2 rounds - RP
Player 2 can win by PS, RS
(PP not allowed because consecutive same moves cannot be played by Player 2)
Answer : 2

Is it a true Permutation problem or does the no consecutive same moves condition make it more of a DP problem?
(I remember that every Permutation/Combination can be a DP but every DP cannot be a Perm/Comb)

PS - This is not part of any active programming contest.
It was a part of an interview round in past and had a time limit of 30 min.

Bruteforce trying to generate each string would not work.

Total ways to win would be sum of the number of ways to win by 1 round, 2 rounds, ...  N rounds.
Without the constraint of no two consecutive moves same, it would be much simpler.

```
For N round wins - 1 way  
For N-1 round wins - N ways (for N-1 wins and 1 draw)  
For N-2 round wins - N*N-1 ways (for N-2 wins and 2 draws) + N ways (for N-1 wins and 1 loss)  
Ans = (1) + (N) + (N*N-1 + N) ...
```

But as soon as the constraint arrives, the sequence of Players 1 moves matter.

Now with the constraint
For N round wins - it may not be possible if the player 1 sequence has even 1 character repeated in sequence
e.g. PRR (cannot win 3 rounds)
Was unable to identify how the number of was for each count of round wins would be.

Comment: Looks like a straightforward DP problem to me, with an O(N^2) space and time solution. You need a 2D DP table. ith row stores the number of ways to win/lose by k points (-i <= k <= i) with the last move of R, P or S, so 3*(2i+1) values in the ith row.

Comment: Thanks. That helps understand the complexity and memory allocation.
But how would the value of  S_Array[i][j] be derived?
S_Array[3][5] would be number of ways to win by 3 points at 6th position in string by playing S. (considering 0 index)
That should be dependent on element in 6th position, correct? 
If it is S,
S_Array[3][5] = R_Array[3][4] + P_Array[3][4]
If it is P,
S_Array[3][5] = R_Array[2][4] + P_Array[2][4]
If it is R,
S_Array[3][5] = R_Array[4][4] + P_Array[4][4]
Is this correct?

Comment: Also, would answer then be:
S_Array[1][n]+S_Array[2][n]+ ... S_Array[n][n]  +
R_Array[1][n]+R_Array[2][n]+ ... R_Array[n][n]  +
P_Array[1][n]+P_Array[2][n]+ ... P_Array[n][n]

Do we need the negative part? Should we not start with 0?

Comment: If the opponent's move #6 is R, then S_Array[i][6] = R_Array[i+1][5] + P_Array[i+1][5] (because S loses), R_Array[i][6] = S_Array[i][5] + P_Array[i][5] (R draws), and P_Array[i][6] = R_Array[i-1][5] + S_Array[i-1][5] (P wins) for all i from -6 to 6.

Comment: Thanks @n.m.couldbeanAI.
Is the final answer part right?
Answer = S_Array[1][n]+S_Array[2][n]+ ... S_Array[n][n] + R_Array[1][n]+R_Array[2][n]+ ... R_Array[n][n] + P_Array[1][n]+P_Array[2][n]+ ... P_Array[n][n]

Comment: yes should be right